# SSRS2014, I can not send multi-parameters to MySQL via ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc, ssrs-2014

I am using SSRS2014 to report data stored in MySQL database.

I get the exception like :

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot add multi value query parameter '?' for dataset 'DataSet1' because it is not supported by the data extension. (rsErrorAddingMultiValueQueryParameter)

My query:

`="SELECT vehicle_id,plate_no,driver_id FROM test_vehicle Where vehicle_id IN ('"+Join(Parameters!Parameter1.Value, "','") + "')"`

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you for any your suggestions.